# Instantiate an instance of all child classes?

Tags: php, oop

I've got a folder of modules in my app. Each of these modules contains a class that extends an abstract "Module_Template" class. Is there a way to instantiate an instance of each class automatically?

```
abstract class Module_Template {}

class Module_A extends Module_Template{}

class Module_B extends Module_Template{}

class Module_C extends Module_Template{}
```

Then elsewhere something like:

```
foreach <child class of Module_Template> {
    $dynamic_name = new <child class of Module_Template>;
}
```

Or is there a better way altogether to accomplish this?

Comment: Do your modules have the same namespace or different?

Comment: They easily could be...